# Is it possible to programmatically increase the height of PDF form text fields using JS in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I'm building a browser-based PDF filler using React.

Users need to be able to fill pre-existing PDF templates which have form fields.

I have a state for each for field that is updated by the user. When user clicks "Export", I currently use **pdf-lib** to update the value of each form field with the state value, and download  the PDF on the user's browser.

The problem is that if the text of a field is bigger than the field size, then text is not entirely visible on the PDF because height of the field is fixed.

I've configured the PDF template to have small font-size and the fields to be scrollable but that's not enough because users have to print PDF on paper, so all text should be visible.

I would like to find a way to increase the height of the fields programmatically.

Open to any sort of help.